# $VV^{-1} \subseteq U$

Tags: general-topology

> If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $e$ (identity) in a topological group,show there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $e$ for which $VV^{-1} \subseteq U$.

It's exercise from Basic topology,Armstrong,Promblem 18 of Chapter 4,and my approach get a little problem,so can you help me???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Use the fact that the map $G\times G\to G$ given by $(g,h)\mapsto gh^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: :but it's not $V \times V$.

Comment: @DanielXu Write out what continuity at $(e,e)$ means for that function!

Comment: @Henno Brandsma There is a neighbourhood of (e,e) whose image is U?

Comment: @DanielXu there is a neighbourhood $O_1 \times O_2$ of $(e,e)$ whose image lies inside $U$. Now take $V= O_1 \cap O_2$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma oh,i get it,thank you.